# How can I detect multiple words from a string? (python)

Tags: python, detect, words

I need to create a program on which a user can input an issue they are having with their phone. As the reply could be multiple words and lines, I need to be able to pick up key phrases and words such as "doesn't turn on" or "cracked" from the reply. Everything I have tried so far hasn't worked; not really an expert with programming, only started recently.

psuedo code:

```
x=input("What is wrong with your phone?")
if "dropped" in x:
    print( #text )
```

I am using Python v3.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use the split() function with the space(whitespace) " " sperator. You don't need argument, split() uses spaces as default separator.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please show what you've tried so far? Do you need a specific approach (e.g. arrays, regexp...)?

Comment: If you have a limited and small set of keywords to look up, then BAH's answer below should suffice.

Comment: What if I have a large set of key words? I think I will be looking to detect about 25 or so words,

Comment: Thank you, I'll be a daily visitor if i want to finish this course :P. No I haven't used any arrays and am not too sure what an ""regexp" is. I think i'll try BAH's way and see if it works. Laur

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach:

```
x = input("What is wrong with your phone?")
keywords = ["doesn't turn on", "cracked", "dropped"]
if any(keyword in x for keyword in keywords):
    print("test")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split()` and then `in`

For example:

```
response = input("What is wrong with your phone?")

responseList = response.split()

if "dropped" in responseList:
    #print( #text )
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code you have already entered.

```
x = input("What is wrong with your phone?")
if "dropped" in x:
   print("You've dropped your phone!")
```